# How to create grid view using jquery in asp.net and click a select Field column, then Update,Delete and Insert new recorde

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0

I want to create a grid view using jQuery in asp.net(C#),in which is a column(select) then click select 
link show all records in the editing form where I want to edit,delete,insert records using jquery.

Comment: Google for it, there is a lot of jquery plug-ins on the internet.
Here is one: http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

there are is a good example. [Exapmple](http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/events_keySubmit.html)
You can user json jquery and http handler for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a table with
.append(html text file)

then with
.ajax() or .post()
send data to codebehind
and in the form load
u can do every thing u want
thw important part is to create it with .append().